# Error compiling android zxing release not debug

Tags: android, release, zxing

I don't figure out why this error.  I was compiling on another computer and the release compilation went ok, but on this computer, I get :

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:app:preBuild
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71910Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices4323Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:crashlyticsCleanupResourcesRelease
:app:crashlyticsUploadStoredDeobsRelease
:app:crashlyticsGenerateResourcesRelease
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:compileReleaseJava
/Users/wimha/wimhaAndroidApp/app/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/AutoFocusManager.java:63: error: method executeOnExecutor in class AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> cannot be applied to given types;
      outstandingTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                     ^
  required: Executor,CAP#1[]
  found: Executor
  reason: formal varargs element type CAP#1 is not accessible from class AutoFocusManager
  where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
/Users/wimha/wimhaAndroidApp/app/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/InactivityTimer.java:52: error: method executeOnExecutor in class AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> cannot be applied to given types;
    inactivityTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                  ^
  required: Executor,CAP#1[]
  found: Executor
  reason: formal varargs element type CAP#1 is not accessible from class InactivityTimer
  where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
/Users/wimha/wimhaAndroidApp/app/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/share/AppPickerActivity.java:35: error: method executeOnExecutor in class AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> cannot be applied to given types;
    backgroundTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                  ^
  required: Executor,CAP#1[]
  found: Executor
  reason: formal varargs element type CAP#1 is not accessible from class AppPickerActivity
  where Params,Progress,Result are type-variables:
    Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Progress extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
    Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
3 errors
:app:compileReleaseJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 56.213 secs
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to uninstall Java 8. Just open "Project structure" (Ctrl+alt+shift+s), select "SDK Location" and set "JDK location" to path, whith JDK 7.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling Java 8 solved it.

[How to uninstall JDK 1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903)

Comment: Using Java 7 for compilation would be a better answer, should you want to suggest to use a more suited java version...

Answer (score 1):

I solved by replacing the anonymous declarations like this

```
private AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> outstaindingTask;
```

with the actual types:

```
private AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> outstandingTask;
```

You can find the list of types to use by looking at the class definition that's instantiated, for example in the case of `AutoFocusManager`:

```
outstandingTask = new AutoFocusTask();
```

The `AutoFocusTask` class is declared as:

```
private final class AutoFocusTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,Object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are compiling this code, but it's correct as Java code. It compiles fine with the Maven build. This seems to be an error in the compiler you are using.

Comment: Uninstalling Java 8 solved it. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903